# Не заносятся координаты с бд в карту

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Не могу понять в чем проблема, делаю запрос с бд и вставляю координаты, а их не заносит.

Вот, что наделал

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['event'])){ 
                    $event_long_lang = $_GET['event'];
                    $sqls = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `events`.id = '$event_long_lang'") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqls)){
                      ?>
                      <!-- Google Maps -->
                      <script type="text/javascript">
                       function initialize() {
                         var latlng = {lat: <?php $row['lat'] ?>, lng: <?php $row['lng'] ?>};
                         var settings = {
                           zoom: 15,
                           center: latlng,
                           mapTypeControl: true,
                           mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                           navigationControl: true,
                           navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                         };
                         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
                          settings);
                       }
                     </script>
                     <div id="map_canvas" style="width:auto; height:500px"></div>
                   <? } }?>
```

Comment: Попробуйте сначала на статичной странице  отрисовать 2-3 маркера, потом уже заворачивайте в PHP код. Как минимум здесь - в цикле создаётся и функция отрисовки и карта. И так для каждого элемента. Причем элементы с одинаковым id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно дело не только в этом, но очевидно что Вы забыли написать echo перед переменными широты и долготы.

То есть вместо

```
<?php $row['lng'] ?>
```

нужно

```
<?php echo $row['lng'] ?>
```